# What is the nature of the `gcc: error: 0": No such file or directory` error?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, configure

I am building multiple libraries from source, checked out at the latest releases. I am sure that I have all the dependencies for these libraries installed. The tools I am using yield correctly built libraries in other systems and install their needed dependencies correctly. However on my current build machine I can configure and compile a bunch of libraries, but then gcc throws the following cryptic error when I try to compile libiconv and libsodium from source:

```
gcc-7: error: 0": No such file or directory
```

I am not looking for a direct solution for this problem, I just want to find out what the nature of this error is, when it is appearing in a successfully configured project.

Edit: The last chunk being run is:
`libtool: compile:  gcc -m64 -I../lib -I./../lib -I../include -I./../include -I.. -I./.. -I/home/ubuntu/build/monero/contrib/depends/x86_64-linux-gnu/include -pipe -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -DLIBDIR=\"/home/ubuntu/build/monero/contrib/depends/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib\" -DBUILDING_LIBICONV -DBUILDING_DLL -DENABLE_RELOCATABLE=1 -DIN_LIBRARY -DINSTALLDIR=\"/home/ubuntu/build/monero/contrib/depends/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib\" -DNO_XMALLOC -Dset_relocation_prefix=libiconv_set_relocation_prefix -Drelocate=libiconv_relocate -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"libiconv\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"libiconv\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"libiconv 0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DINSTALLPREFIX=\"/home/ubuntu/build/monero/contrib/depends/x86_64-linux-gnu\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_ATTRIBS_EXT__=1 -D__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__=1 -D__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_DFP_EXT__=1 -D__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_FUNCS_EXT__=1 -D__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__=1 -D__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__=1 -D__STDC_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_VISIBILITY=1 -DLIBICONV_PLUG -c ./../lib/iconv.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o objects/.libs/iconv.o`

What strikes me there is the "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"libiconv 0\"" , which could lead to the string being read as seperate arguments. I do not understand though why this passes on some systems and not on others.

Comment: Are you trying to build in a directory which has space characters in its name, or the name of a parent directory?

Comment: Check for Windows-style line endings somewhere. On Windows, `\r\n` marks the end of a line; on Unix/Linux, it's just `\n` and the `\r` can be taken as the last character of a file name. The error message prints the `\r` character, causing the cursor to move to the beginning of the line, and some of the rest of the message is overwritten. Try `gcc ... 2>&1 | cat -A` to show what's actually being printed in the error message.

Comment: You need to supply more information. GCC is trying to compile a file called `0"`. Hazarding a guess, I'd say the problem is with your build script and libsodium. Run your script with `bash -x` and post the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to find out what the nature of this error is

gcc is being asked to compile or possibly link with a commandline in which
a file is specified, probably via a variable, whose name is a quoted
string of the form:

```
"<something> 0"
```

This won't work, because gcc parses two commandline arguments:

```
"<something>
```

and

```
0"
```

For example:

```
$ touch foo.c
$ name="\"foo 0\""
$ gcc -o $name foo.c
gcc: error: 0": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Some projects sometimes configure with a Package name string in the format of: PACKAGE_STRING="$packagename $version" with a white space in between. This white space can end up not terminated correctly, so gcc will interpret the entire string as two separate commands. The solution is then to either patch the name in the input configure.ac , or if it is already a pre-configured project to patch the name string to one without the whitespace, or the whitespace correctly formatted.